# Selecting a single object from an array to display in a view [Angular]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I've similarly asked this before, but neither solution proved useful.

I currently have a store app built with AngularJS, my problem is, I need to be able to click on one item and open into the "item" view and display only the information with a matching ID from the items array stored in a services.

For example. Item one displayed on store view has an id of 1, and on the store displays the product name etc. When clicked, the item is opened with the item view to display just that product and it's information.

Here's my store Controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope, StoreService){
    $scope.items = StoreService.items();
  });
```

Services (Shortened to save spare, there's 12 other items).

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .service("StoreService", function() {
    var items = [ {
      itemId: 1,
      qty: 0,
      stock: 5,
      price: 99.00,
      name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, Patent Black',
      category: 'Womens Footerwear'
    },
      {
        qty: 0,
        stock: 4,
        price: 42.00,
        name: 'Suede Shoes, Blue',
        category: 'Womens Footerwear'
      }];
    this.items = function() {
      return items;
    };
  });
```

Store View

```
<!-- Start of item iteration -->
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- Start of item -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item_info">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Bn1iB6X.jpg"/>
          <div class="item_footer">
            <div class="info_text">
              <h2>{{item.name| limitTo: 8}}...</h2>
              <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <a ng-href="#"><button role="button">More</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- End of item -->
  </div>
<!-- End of item iteration-->
```

Item Ctrl

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('itemCtrl', function ($scope, StoreService) {

    $scope.items = StoreService.items();
  });
```

Item View

```
<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

<div ng-repreat="item in items">
<div class="item-page-container">
  <div class="item-p-img">
    {{item.name}}

  </div>
  <div class="item-p-tab-Container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Please ask for any more code or for easier view, see my [Github Repo](https://github.com/BillyPurvis/angular-store-app)

Please be clear on the function, feel free to put into a plunker, my Javascript skills come from Angular, but searching an array like this I haven't done before. I'd need a good solution where I can transfer/learn the logic.

Comment: couple of questions Billy, in your item view, why are you iterating over all items? and in your item ctrl again you iterate over all items?

Comment: Hey Jax, thanks for responding. 

I'm still new, but, without iterating ng-repeat in the Item View, the data wouldn't display if I manually specified an item. 

If I'm doing it wrong, by all means tell me a better method. :)

Comment: @BillyPurvis, can you provide [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) what you have?

Comment: I can't seem to get a plunkr working for some reason, it's not something I've used much before.

Comment: @BillyPurvis : Is it possible for you to make one more service? fetch the data based on id. So that in your details page you can call this new service

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I could make another service if it were necessary, what sort of logic would I be needing?

Answer (score 0):

Store View
(not sure about your routing) but would try smt like this:

```
<a ng-href="/items/{{item.itemID}}"><button role="button">More</button></a>
```

this should send you to your item view.

In your Item ctrl, if you inject $routeParams you could fetch the id like so:

```
 item_id = $routeParams.id
```

and then search for your item like so:

```
items = StoreService.items();
$scope.item = items.indexOf(item_id)
```

so in your item view remove the ng-repeat and work with the item object.

As I said before, not enterily sure of your project's structures,. but this should get you on your way.

Comment: Hey - thanks, it doesn't work, just defaults to the home page once I've cried. I noticed itemID was mentioned, but then item_id, would they all need to me itemID? Would you prefer I updated my item's controller?

Comment: Yeah also pop in your routes

Answer (score 0):

Make your routes like this :

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/items', {
            templateUrl: 'yourtemplate-path/items.html',
            controller: 'yourItemController'
        })
        .when('/items/:itemId', {
            templateUrl: 'yourtemplate-path/items-detail.html',
            controller: 'yourItemDetailsController'
        })
```

Your controller:

For items,

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope, StoreService){
    StoreService.items(function(){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
  });
```

For item detail page,

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('storeDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, StoreService){
    StoreService.items({itemId: $routeParams.itemId}, function(){
        $scope.item = data;
    });
  });
```

and create your new service, which fetches the data based on this id(itemId)

NOTE: I didn't tested the code.